# nginx reverse proxy and pega

Tags: redirect, nginx, pega

I am trying to configure Pega web UI through Nginx. I am getting the front page but, Pega CSS, images and js is not loading. Below is my configuration.

```
location /prweb/PRServlet/ {
   rewrite  ^/prweb/PRServlet/(.*)$ /pega/$1 redirect;
}
location  /pega {
  proxy_pass   http://example.com:8083/prweb/PRServlet;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ???

Answer (score 0):

Static files like js and CSS are loaded from root directory which is **prweb**. May be you need to tinker to serve from prweb instead of PRServlet.